# Unable to find assembly 'NHibernate.Search

Tags: nhibernate, exception, .net-assembly

I am getting the following error intermittently on one of our build environments (not on my local machine) - ignore the NH version - I compiled the assembly form source. The app pool is then restarted in iis. I cannot find out where this is originating from. Any ideas?

```
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: DefaultDomain

Process ID: 2428

Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Message: Unable to find assembly 'NHibernate.Search, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

StackTrace:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.AppDomain.Deserialize(Byte[] blob)
   at System.AppDomain.UnmarshalObject(Byte[] blob)
```

Comment: do you have a solution for this ? I have a very similar stack trace..